# ASP.NET Usercontrol + Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, user-controls

I have an usercontrol with javascript inside. I'm using it into a page with ASP.NET Ajax enabled. It works fine in most scenarios, but when the instance of the usercontrol is not visible in the first request and I make visible through an Ajax postback the javascript is not executed. Any help?

Comment: Can you provide some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

when you set user control `visible="false"` the content of that control will not render instead use `style="display:none"` to hide the control that way the content of the control will render.

Comment: Hey @bobby, thanks for ask. You're right, but what if the control is inside a non-visible container. We would have the same problem and we can't control the whole hierarchy. So, we moved all the javascript to a file. I know this is not the best solution, but it worked for us. Thanks!

Comment: Any control that is inside an invisible container will not render regardless.  I've gotten around a similar problem by having a second control in the page (outside of the invisible container) with `style='display:none'` just so it will render the relevant js functions. Like yours, it is not the best solution but it works. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

When using `Control1.Visible = false;` your control will not render on your page at all.

The async postback you are using does not re-render the entire page. If your control was injecting javascript to the page this javascript will not render.

A quick and dirty work around for your control is to use.

`Control1.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none;")` to hide
`Control1.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block;")` to show

Comment: Thanks Biff MaGriff, check my comments for the firts post.